# Integral approximations.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume we have a general function $ \varphi $ such that $$ \intop_{a}^{b}|\varphi\left(t\right)|dt<\infty $$

It is well known that for any $\varepsilon>0 $ one can find a continuous function $ f $, such that $$ \intop_{a}^{b}|\varphi\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|dt<\varepsilon\, $$

I wonder it is possible to prove a stronger claim. Given $ \varepsilon>0 $ is it possible to find continuously differentiable $ f $ such that $$ \intop_{a}^{b}|\varphi\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|dt<\varepsilon\, $$ ?

If it is indeed possible, can we go further? is it possible for any $ \varepsilon>0 $ to find for any $n\in \mathbb{N} $ $f\in C^n((a,b)) $ such that $$ \intop_{a}^{b}|\varphi\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|dt<\varepsilon\, $$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, if you know Weirstrass' approximation theorem you can even choose f to be a polynomial (assuming a, b are finite)

Comment: @peek-a-boo So we can even choose $ f $ to be analytic function?

Comment: yes, polynomial implies analytic

Comment: Weierstraß theorem in this case is a bad choice. $\varphi$ needs to be continuous at $[a, b]$ which we do not know at all.

Comment: @Meowdog But we can approximate $\varphi $ in $L^1 $ norm with continuous function and then approximate the continuous function with Weierstraß theorem

Comment: @meowdog I should have clarified: given phi, find a continuous f like above, then uniformly approximate f using a polynomial P (in my first comment when I said you can choose f to be polynomial i already changed notation from P to f)

Comment: @FreeZeThis is true. But I am not sure if we can approximate $\varphi$ by functions that are continuous on $[a, b]$, i.e. the closure. $(a, b)$ is always possible, but what if $\varphi$ explodes at either $a$ or $b$?

Comment: @meowdog one can always approximate by step functions first(this is true even on the whole real line) , then approximate these by continuous functions (so the endpoint issue doesn't come up) then using Weirstrass upgrade to a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is of course possible. The key words here are mollifier and Dirac-sequence. Meaning that this approximation can be achieved by convolution of a smooth so called kernel and $\varphi$.

This can be read in "Evans, Gariepy - Measure theory and fine properties of functions" (chapter 4.2) and "Alt - linear functional analysis". It is one of the classic results in approximation theory. Namely it is:

*If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is nonempty and open, then $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, i.e. the $C^\infty(\Omega)$ functions with compact support in $\Omega$ are dense in $L^1(\Omega)$, the space of integrable functions on $\Omega$.*